# How to drag v-chip using draggable

Tags: vue.js, draggable

I'm trying to drag a v-chip in vue using the draggable lib, but it doesn't work :(

when I put the draggable tag before the Combobox tag, I can see that the Combobox can be drugged.

but I need to be able to drug the chips...

attached here my HTML code:

```html
                 <v-combobox
                    style="
                      padding-right: 30px !important;
                      padding-left: 30px !important;
                    "
                    v-model="chips"
                    :items="items"
                    chips
                    clearable
                    color="#0D47A1"
                    label="Your actions..."
                    multiple
                    readonly="true"
                  >
                    <template
                      v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item, select, selectedSetups }"
                      style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Segoe UI Emoji'"
                    >
                    <draggable v-model="chips"
                    @start="dragging = true"
                    @end="dragging = false">
                    <v-chip
                        v-bind="attrs"
                        :input-value="selectedSetups"
                        color
                        close
                        label
                        @click="select"
                        @click:close="RemoveRequirement(item)"
                        outlined
                      >
                        <span>{{ item.category }}</span
                        >&nbsp;
                        <v-divider
                          class="mx-4"
                          color="black"
                          inset
                          vertical
                          v-show="item.value.toString() != ''"
                        ></v-divider>
                        <span>{{ item.value.toString() }}</span>
                      </v-chip>
                   </draggable>
                    </template>
                  </v-combobox>
```

any idea what's wrong here?

would be very grateful for the help

Comment: This article can be usefull https://learnvue.co/2020/01/how-to-add-drag-and-drop-to-your-vuejs-project/

Comment: Or this one that's more direction "move" https://vuejsexamples.com/a-vue-component-or-component-wrapper-that-makes-an-element-movable/